# A red line is appearing under package main in go in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration, gopls

[image]

I get the necessary output but I can't get rid of the red line

I tried entering this "gopls": {
"experimentalWorkspaceModule": true,
}

But got this:
gopls was not able to find modules in your workspace.
When outside of GOPATH, gopls needs to know which modules you are working on.
You can fix this by opening your workspace to a folder inside a Go module, or
by using a go.work file to specify multiple modules.
See the documentation for more information on setting up your workspace:
https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/workspace.md.

Comment: Have you run [`go mod init`](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/create-module) to initialize your Go project?

Answer (score 1):

Run `go mod init blank` in the terminal. Then run `go mod tidy`. This will solve your issue.

Answer (score -3):

Run `go mod init main` in the terminal next to your `main.go` file. This will create the `go.mod` file which will hold the package dependencies for your project. Then, to download the packages, you can run `go mod tidy` which will create the `go.sum` file (if necessary). These are needed to use go modules in your project, when working outside of the your go root folder.

Comment: `main` is the name of the package, almost certainly not the correct name for the module.